# Theme json causing Error 404 The site could not be found

Tags: wordpress, custom-error-pages

I have created several "fake" pages on my website to display information from another database. I recently adopted the Gutenberg editor blocks in the theme but I run into this problem. If I include the theme.json in the root folder of the domain, the "fake" pages are not displayed and return the 404 error. If I remove the theme.json file, I lose the css styles but the pages work again. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'generate_fake_page', 0);
function generate_fake_page($posts) {
        $post = new stdClass;
            $post->post_author    = 1;
            $post->post_name      = $url_slug;
            $post->guid           = home_url() . '/other/';
            $post->post_title     = 'My fake page';
            // content 
            $post->post_content   = $content;
            $post->ID             = $my_uniq_id;
            $post->post_type      = 'page';
            $post->post_status    = 'static';
            $post->post_excerpt   = '';
            $post->comment_status = 'closed';
            $post->ping_status    = 'open';
            $post->comment_count  = 0;
            $post->post_date      = $my_date
            $post->post_date_gmt  = $my_date;
            $posts                = NULL;
            $posts[]              = $post;

            // make wpQuery believe this is a real page too
            $wp_query->is_page             = true;
            $wp_query->is_singular         = true;
            $wp_query->is_home             = false;
            $wp_query->is_archive          = false;
            $wp_query->is_category         = false;
            $wp_query->is_attachment       = false;
            unset( $wp_query->query[ 'error' ] );
            $wp_query->query_vars[ 'error' ] = '';
            $wp_query->is_404 = false;
    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmz, weird. I had the same thing here. I did solved it, but I don't know if this solves your problem. I will just write down my journey and hope you can extract some info from it to point you in the correct direction:

*Backgroud information:* What happend was that I had a page https://project.local/slovenie/ and I had a Facet on it that showed a list of Taxonomy Terms. One of these term had the same slug as the page it was shown on.

So this triggered a 404 https://project.local/slovenie/?fwp_regios_select=slovenie

*1st try:* First I thought my issue was with FacetWP and preloading some value via `facetwp_preload_url_vars`. I disable the filter and it started working. But there was nothing weird going on in FacetWP.

But alas, it wasn't that. This should have worked.

*2nd try:* Ok, let's search a bit further. I'm working on a multisite with a weird construction and a lot of "switch blogs" here and there.

I disabled initializing of code step by step. A `parse_query` here,
and I landed a `pre_get_posts`.

Ok, back to my issue: In my `pre_get_post` I did a `$query->is_archive()` check. Not a `\is_archive()`, but the variable on the `wp_query`. Also `wp_template`, `wp_template_part`, `acf-taxonomy`, `acf-post-type` and `my-custom-post-type` or in my case `[0 => 'page']` the query of the page I was on.

The `$query->is_archive()` is also `TRUE` for things like `menu_nav_items`, so I saw that I needed to change my code there. I added a check if this `pre_get_posts` was for my `custom-post-type` by checking

Btw! I noticed a `"post_type" => "wp_global_styles"` the moment I created my `theme.json`. So somewhere stuff is being queried and probaly `the_posts` doesn't always expects what you are filling in `$posts`.

Possible solution for you: Do a check on the `WP_Query $query` which can be passed as 2nd argument on `the_posts`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_posts/ Something like:

`( isset( $query->query['post_type'] ) && \is_array( $query->query['post_type'] ) && \in_array('page', $query->query['post_type'] ) )` or if `$query->query['post_type']` is a string, then check if it's a string. But you catch my drift.

Or you add your filter inside an conditional within the `wp` action, but I don't know if that might be to late.

I hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I re-checked you code and found the flaw that you aren't passing the `$wp_query` to the filter, that way you are getting a fatal error when you arre setting the properties on this.

** Pass 2 arguments**

```
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'generate_fake_page', 0, 2);
```

```
function generate_fake_page( $posts, $wp_query ) {
}
```

And you need to conver it to a WP_Post class like `$wp_post = new WP_Post( $post );`. Be sure to set the filter to `raw` like `$post->filter = 'raw'; // important!`.

Secondly, check out this tutorial by
Barn2 company that Andy wrote. I tested it and it worked wíth a theme.json: https://barn2.com/blog/create-fake-wordpress-post-fly/